# IPv6 static routes

Tags: linux, networking, centos, routing, ipv6

I am looking to configure a few hosts with IPv6 on my network. The router (running CentOS 5) is configured with an Hurricane Electric (HE) tunnel which works fine on that host.

However, I would like to statically add a few additional hosts on the same LAN to have IPv6 through this tunnel. No, I don't want radvd or dhcpv6 to do the work for me in this case.

I already have IPv6 forwarding enabled in sysctl.conf. I am looking for help with the next steps (statically adding the routes).

Lets say the IP addresses are as follows:

Router: 2001:470:1b07:1::

Host1: 2001:470:1b07:2::

How would I go about making them see each other? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need:

1. you need two /64 prefixes, one on the tunnel and one on the LAN
2. the router needs an address on both the tunnel interface and the LAN interface in the corresponding /64 prefixes
3. the router has a default route to the tunnel
4. the router will automatically have a route for the LAN /64 to the LAN interface
5. The PC on the LAN gets another address from the LAN /64
6. The PC has a static default route towards the LAN address of the router

Now the IPv6 traffic from the PC will be sent to the router, which will send it to on tunnel. Return traffic from come from the tunnel to the router, which will then see that the destination is in the LAN /64 and it will send it to its LAN interface where the PC can receive it.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I have completed steps 1-3. The router has full v6 connectivity. However, while I understand what you are outlining, can you provide further detail for step 4 and 6? I have already assigned the LAN PC (not router) to have an address from the LAN IPv6 subnet.

Comment: The LAN interface of the router needs to have a LAN interface IP.

Comment: What Jeff said :-)  Both the router and the PC need to have an address on the LAN to be able to communicate. Without it the router can't be the default gateway to the rest of the internet for the PC. (Technically not true, it can be a default gateway using link-local addresses, which is what happens when it sends out RAs. Manually configuring that is error-prone though, so it is much easier to give the router a global address on the LAN interface)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all very much for the help. All my troubles actually stemmed from a typo in my Network Configuration script for the interface. Put simply, I was over thinking this problem and doubting myself in this case.

When populated with IPV6INIT, IPV6ADDR and IPV6_DEFAULTGW (on both the router and other LAN machine) no further routes needed to be added. The static assignment/routes now work.

Comment: If you appreciate the help then please mark the answer as accepted :-)